# Excel formula text to minutes

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to convert text to minutes.

text hours = 8.15 'means 8h 15m

convert to minutes formula

```
=LEFT(A2,2)*60+IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(".",A2))=TRUE, SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,2),".",""), "0")`
```

I getting error when calculate "0.15"

Please help, Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to extract minute part or calculate total minute?

Comment: I have a simplification for you: `IsWhatever(...=TRUE)` is the same as `IsWhatever(...)`, so in your case `ISNUMBER(SEARCH(".",A2))=TRUE` can be replaced by `ISNUMBER(SEARCH(".",A2))`.

Comment: `8.15` does it mean 8,15 hours (so that would be 8 hours and 9 minutes) or does it means 8 hours and 15 minutes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Total minute

```
=INT(A1)*60+(A1-INT(A1))*100
```

[image]

If want to extract minutes only then use

```
=A1-INT(A1)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Not clear exactly what you want, or exactly what you are dealing with.

*The below assumes that **dot** is your system decimal separator.  If **dot** is not your system decimal separator, then replace the cell references in the formulas below with:  `SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","your_system_decimal_separator")`*

Assuming `8.15` means `8 hrs 15 minutes`, you can convert it to Excel time value with:

```
=DOLLARDE(A1,60)/24
```

and format the result as time (eg `hh:mm` or `[mm]` or similar).

If what you really want to see is the minutes as an integer (not as a time), then use

```
=DOLLARDE(A1,60)*60
```

`DOLLARDE(A1,60)` converts `8.15` to `8` + `15/60` (decimal hours) (e.g. `8.25`)

Dividing by `24` or multiplying by `60` converts it either to an Excel time value, or decimal minutes, respectively, as Excel stores time (and dates) as fractions of a day.

*Note: If `8.15` is decimal hours and equal to `8:09`, then you don't need the `DOLLARDDE` part of the formula at all*

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify if 8.15 means 8,15 hours in decimal (it would be equal to 8 hours and 9 minutes) or if it means 8 hours and 15 minutes, so I developed both.

I guess the problem is that your decimal separator is the comma, and you need to convert the value into numeric.

[image]

My formulas for first version:

1. B5: `=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A5;".";","))*60`
2. C5:`=INT(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A5;".";",")))*60`
3. D5:`=B5-C5`

My formulas for second version:

1. B11: `=(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A11;".";","))-VALUE(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A11;".";","))))*100+INT(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A11;".";",")))*60`
2. C11:`=INT(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A11;".";",")))*60`
3. D11:`=B11-C11`

With this formulas you convert the string into numeric value, and then you work in the decimal system.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
=minute(substitute(a2;".";":"))/100
```

to get "0.15" from "8.15".

Comment: `=A1-INT(A1)` this will extract decimal part even if it is stored as text.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two possible problems in your question: either Excel can't recognise your "8.15" as being a timevalue, or you don't know how to calculate the number of minutes from a timevalue.

In case it's the second one, there's an easy formula for this:

```
=Hour(A2)*60 + Minute(A2)
```

Meanwhile I keep digging for a while to recognise "8.15" as a timevalue.

If ever you have the possibility to replace the "." by a ":", this might solve your problem immediately.